# Format number different depending on mobile or business phone

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, number-formatting

Currently in my php application I have the following code that formats the unformatted 10 digit australian phone number to `XX XXXX XXXX`. What I would like to do is if the phone number in the database starts with `04` then it will format it as 4,3,3 like `XXXX XXX XXX` otherwise will maintain the 2,4,4 formatting. All phone numbers are stored in the database as `XXXXXXXXXX`.

Here is my code so hopefully someone can shed some light. I know there needs to be an if statement, but unsure how to check the first 2 digits of the number for the `04`.

```
<?php

    $num = $record['busphone'];
    $phoneformated = substr($num,0,2)." ".substr($num,4,4)." ".substr($num,6);

    echo "Ph: " . $phoneformated;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the substring in an `if` statement:

```
if (substr($num, 0, 2) == '04') {
    $phoneformatted = substr($num, 0, 4) . " " . substr($num, 4, 3) . " " . substr($num, 7);
} else {
    $phoneformatted = substr($num, 0, 2) . " " . substr($num, 2, 4) . " " . substr($num, 6);
}
```

Notice that you had a typo in formatting the residential numbers, `substr($num, 4, 4)` should be `substr($num, 2, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Here's an `if` statement

```
$prefix = substr($num,0,2);
if($prefix == '04') {
    $phoneformated = $prefix . " ".substr($num,2,4)." ".substr($num,-6);
} else {
    $phoneformated = substr($num,0,4)." ".substr($num,2,3)." ".substr($num,-3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps... exactly what I was looking for. I noticed a regex-style one above... Are there pros/cons to either?

Comment: For something this simple I'd stick with `substr`. There's a performance hit using regex but the difference is likely not major here

Answer (score 0):

Match First 04 with regex

```
$num = $record['busphone'];
// check first 04
if( preg_match('/^04/', $num) ) {
   // Your format
   // xxxx xxx xxx
}
else {
    // xxxxxxxxxx
}
```

Comment: What is `+` followed by `{2}`? `+` means "1 or more", `{2}` means exactly 2. If you meant `[04]{2}`, that will match `00`, `40`, and `44` as well.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, didn't tried these macthed values, thanks you so much for guidence.